# Wordpress data in Maui using Wp API, Json attempting to process

Tags: c#, json, .net, wordpress-rest-api, maui

I'm trying to figure out what is the problem for recover data from Wordpress site inside my MAUI application.
I type my model using Json2csharp:

```
    public class WpPost
{
    // Root myDeserializedClass = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Root>>(myJsonResponse);
    public class About
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("href")]
        public string Href;
    }

    public class Author
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string Name;

        [JsonPropertyName("@id")]
        public string Id;

        [JsonPropertyName("embeddable")]
        public bool Embeddable;

        [JsonPropertyName("href")]
        public string Href;
    }

    public class Breadcrumb
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("@id")]
        public string Id;
    }

    public class Collection
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("href")]
        public string Href;
    }

    public class Content
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("rendered")]
        public string Rendered;

        [JsonPropertyName("protected")]
        public bool Protected;
    }

    public class Cury
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string Name;

        [JsonPropertyName("href")]
        public string Href;

        [JsonPropertyName("templated")]
        public bool Templated;
    }

    public class Excerpt
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("rendered")]
        public string Rendered;

        [JsonPropertyName("protected")]
        public bool Protected;
    }

    public class Graph
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("@type")]
        public object Type;

        [JsonPropertyName("@id")]
        public string Id;

        [JsonPropertyName("url")]
        public string Url;

        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string Name;

        [JsonPropertyName("description")]
        public string Description;

        [JsonPropertyName("publisher")]
        public Publisher Publisher;

        [JsonPropertyName("potentialAction")]
        public List<PotentialAction> PotentialAction;

        [JsonPropertyName("inLanguage")]
        public string InLanguage;

        [JsonPropertyName("isPartOf")]
        public IsPartOf IsPartOf;

        [JsonPropertyName("datePublished")]
        public DateTime? DatePublished;

        [JsonPropertyName("dateModified")]
        public DateTime? DateModified;

        [JsonPropertyName("breadcrumb")]
        public Breadcrumb Breadcrumb;

        [JsonPropertyName("itemListElement")]
        public List<ItemListElement> ItemListElement;

        [JsonPropertyName("author")]
        public Author Author;

        [JsonPropertyName("headline")]
        public string Headline;

        [JsonPropertyName("mainEntityOfPage")]
        public MainEntityOfPage MainEntityOfPage;

        [JsonPropertyName("wordCount")]
        public int? WordCount;

        [JsonPropertyName("commentCount")]
        public int? CommentCount;

        [JsonPropertyName("articleSection")]
        public List<string> ArticleSection;

        [JsonPropertyName("image")]
        public Image Image;

        [JsonPropertyName("logo")]
        public Logo Logo;
    }

    public class Guid
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("rendered")]
        public string Rendered;
    }

    public class Image
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("@type")]
        public string Type;

        [JsonPropertyName("inLanguage")]
        public string InLanguage;

        [JsonPropertyName("@id")]
        public string Id;

        [JsonPropertyName("url")]
        public string Url;

        [JsonPropertyName("contentUrl")]
        public string ContentUrl;

        [JsonPropertyName("caption")]
        public string Caption;
    }

    public class IsPartOf
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("@id")]
        public string Id;
    }

    public class ItemListElement
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("@type")]
        public string Type;

        [JsonPropertyName("position")]
        public int Position;

        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string Name;

        [JsonPropertyName("item")]
        public string Item;
    }

    public class Links
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("self")]
        public List<Self> Self;

        [JsonPropertyName("collection")]
        public List<Collection> Collection;

        [JsonPropertyName("about")]
        public List<About> About;

        [JsonPropertyName("author")]
        public List<Author> Author;

        [JsonPropertyName("replies")]
        public List<Reply> Replies;

        [JsonPropertyName("version-history")]
        public List<VersionHistory> VersionHistory;

        [JsonPropertyName("predecessor-version")]
        public List<PredecessorVersion> PredecessorVersion;

        [JsonPropertyName("wp:attachment")]
        public List<WpAttachment> WpAttachment;

        [JsonPropertyName("wp:term")]
        public List<WpTerm> WpTerm;

        [JsonPropertyName("curies")]
        public List<Cury> Curies;
    }

    public class Logo
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("@id")]
        public string Id;
    }

    public class MainEntityOfPage
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("@id")]
        public string Id;
    }

    public class Meta
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("jetpack_publicize_message")]
        public string JetpackPublicizeMessage;

        [JsonPropertyName("jetpack_is_tweetstorm")]
        public bool JetpackIsTweetstorm;

        [JsonPropertyName("jetpack_publicize_feature_enabled")]
        public bool JetpackPublicizeFeatureEnabled;
    }

    public class OgImage
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("url")]
        public string Url;
    }

    public class PotentialAction
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("@type")]
        public string Type;

        [JsonPropertyName("target")]
        public object Target;

        [JsonPropertyName("query-input")]
        public string QueryInput;

        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string Name;
    }

    public class PredecessorVersion
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public int Id;

        [JsonPropertyName("href")]
        public string Href;
    }

    public class Publisher
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("@id")]
        public string Id;
    }

    public class Reply
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("embeddable")]
        public bool Embeddable;

        [JsonPropertyName("href")]
        public string Href;
    }

    public class Robots
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("index")]
        public string Index;

        [JsonPropertyName("follow")]
        public string Follow;

        [JsonPropertyName("max-snippet")]
        public string MaxSnippet;

        [JsonPropertyName("max-image-preview")]
        public string MaxImagePreview;

        [JsonPropertyName("max-video-preview")]
        public string MaxVideoPreview;
    }

    public class Root
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public int Id;

        [JsonPropertyName("date")]
        public DateTime Date;

        [JsonPropertyName("date_gmt")]
        public DateTime DateGmt;

        [JsonPropertyName("guid")]
        public Guid Guid;

        [JsonPropertyName("modified")]
        public DateTime Modified;

        [JsonPropertyName("modified_gmt")]
        public DateTime ModifiedGmt;

        [JsonPropertyName("slug")]
        public string Slug;

        [JsonPropertyName("status")]
        public string Status;

        [JsonPropertyName("type")]
        public string Type;

        [JsonPropertyName("link")]
        public string Link;

        [JsonPropertyName("title")]
        public Title Title;

        [JsonPropertyName("content")]
        public Content Content;

        [JsonPropertyName("excerpt")]
        public Excerpt Excerpt;

        [JsonPropertyName("author")]
        public int Author;

        [JsonPropertyName("featured_media")]
        public int FeaturedMedia;

        [JsonPropertyName("comment_status")]
        public string CommentStatus;

        [JsonPropertyName("ping_status")]
        public string PingStatus;

        [JsonPropertyName("sticky")]
        public bool Sticky;

        [JsonPropertyName("template")]
        public string Template;

        [JsonPropertyName("format")]
        public string Format;

        [JsonPropertyName("meta")]
        public Meta Meta;

        [JsonPropertyName("categories")]
        public List<int> Categories;

        [JsonPropertyName("tags")]
        public List<object> Tags;

        [JsonPropertyName("jetpack_publicize_connections")]
        public List<object> JetpackPublicizeConnections;

        [JsonPropertyName("yoast_head")]
        public string YoastHead;

        [JsonPropertyName("yoast_head_json")]
        public YoastHeadJson YoastHeadJson;

        [JsonPropertyName("jetpack_featured_media_url")]
        public string JetpackFeaturedMediaUrl;

        [JsonPropertyName("jetpack_sharing_enabled")]
        public bool JetpackSharingEnabled;

        [JsonPropertyName("jetpack_likes_enabled")]
        public bool JetpackLikesEnabled;

        [JsonPropertyName("_links")]
        public Links Links;
    }

    public class Schema
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("@context")]
        public string Context;

        [JsonPropertyName("@graph")]
        public List<Graph> Graph;
    }

    public class Self
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("href")]
        public string Href;
    }

    public class Title
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("rendered")]
        public string Rendered;
    }

    public class TwitterMisc
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("Scritto da")]
        public string ScrittoDa;

        [JsonPropertyName("Tempo di lettura stimato")]
        public string TempoDiLetturaStimato;
    }

    public class VersionHistory
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("count")]
        public int Count;

        [JsonPropertyName("href")]
        public string Href;
    }

    public class WpAttachment
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("href")]
        public string Href;
    }

    public class WpTerm
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("taxonomy")]
        public string Taxonomy;

        [JsonPropertyName("embeddable")]
        public bool Embeddable;

        [JsonPropertyName("href")]
        public string Href;
    }

    public class YoastHeadJson
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("title")]
        public string Title;

        [JsonPropertyName("description")]
        public string Description;

        [JsonPropertyName("robots")]
        public Robots Robots;

        [JsonPropertyName("canonical")]
        public string Canonical;

        [JsonPropertyName("og_locale")]
        public string OgLocale;

        [JsonPropertyName("og_type")]
        public string OgType;

        [JsonPropertyName("og_title")]
        public string OgTitle;

        [JsonPropertyName("og_description")]
        public string OgDescription;

        [JsonPropertyName("og_url")]
        public string OgUrl;

        [JsonPropertyName("og_site_name")]
        public string OgSiteName;

        [JsonPropertyName("article_published_time")]
        public DateTime ArticlePublishedTime;

        [JsonPropertyName("article_modified_time")]
        public DateTime ArticleModifiedTime;

        [JsonPropertyName("og_image")]
        public List<OgImage> OgImage;

        [JsonPropertyName("author")]
        public string Author;

        [JsonPropertyName("twitter_card")]
        public string TwitterCard;

        [JsonPropertyName("twitter_misc")]
        public TwitterMisc TwitterMisc;

        [JsonPropertyName("schema")]
        public Schema Schema;
    }
```

I've created a service and injected it in singleton way inside my ViewModel,
Service:

```
public Tive6Service()
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<WpPost>> GetAllWpPostsAsync()
    {            
        try
        {
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(UriString + "/wp/v2/posts");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                posts = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<WpPost>>();
            }
            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", e.Message, "Cancel");
        }
        return posts;
    }

    public async Task<WpPost> GetPostAsync(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(UriString + "/wp/v2/posts"+ id.ToString());
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                post = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<WpPost>();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", e.Message, "Cancel");
        }
        return post;
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
   public NewsViewModel(Tive6Service tive6Service)
    {
        Tive6Service = tive6Service;
        LoadPosts();
       
    }

    Task<ObservableCollection<WpPost>> LoadPosts()
    {            
        posts = new ObservableCollection<WpPost>(Tive6Service.GetAllWpPostsAsync().Result);
        return Task.FromResult(posts);  
    }
```

But during Debug the application stuck in the thread for recover all the WpPost, without throwing exceptions. Deepen in details, using method

> post = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

it works, so the Web Api of the website are ok, like its swagger show me before that.
What and where I'm wrong?

Thanks for your kindness

Comment: which specific line is it stuck on?

Comment: If it is stuck on `posts = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<WpPost>>();`, then its having trouble with the format for a sequence of WpPosts. Add to question the **json** it is attempting to process.

Comment: Yep, it stuck exactly there, thanks for the answer i'm going to add it on question and maybe I'll add json tag

Comment: I'd start by breaking up that statement.  Get the json in one line, then deserialize in another.

Comment: The library to manage json in maui is little bit different from others in other application, i'm not sure that i'm able to breaking up the statement like you suggest but I'll try e giovedì you a response. Thanks

Comment: I don’t see why you couldn’t.  The official docs show the request and the deserialization as two different steps.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/rest

Comment: You're right mate, but the application stuck exactly where I make the call to get the posts here:    'var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(UriString + "/wp/v2/posts" '
  , so I don't know what is the problem here, I'm struggling with it, at this time might be faster create new posts instead recover them from this website. In the Debug window I can read this lines: '[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.IO.Compression.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/com.companyname.mauiapptive6/files/.__override__/System.IO.Compression.dll [External]'

Comment: Is there full error log about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem changing the line of code below in Service class:

```
var response = _httpClient.GetAsync(UriString + "/wp/v2/posts").Result;
```

Now it works.
Thanks to everyone.